# Did The Force Awakens use any screen wipes to transition from scene to scene?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, behind-the-scenes, production

When *Episode VII* was announced, I remember hearing fans wonder whether Abrams would use to the screen wipes to transition from scene to scene the way other *Star Wars* films did.

This [BostonGlobe article](https://www.bostonglobe.com/arts/movies/2015/12/15/the-force-with-star-wars-the-force-awakens/KyOQ1W4zeMyVDncrIirp5M/story.html) seems to think Abrams *did* end up using the *Star Wars* wipe transition:

> Director J.J. Abrams [...] uses old-fashioned screen wipes to transition from scene to scene

However I don't remember noticing any in the film. **Were there any wipe transitions in *The Force Awakens*?**

Comment: I’m fairly sure he did. I seem to recall sitting in the theatre watching _TFA_, and then having a screen wipe quite unwittingly bring back memories of the earlier films. Can’t remember where it was, but even though I’d never particularly noticed the screen wipes in the older films, I was suddenly forcefully reminded of them at some point during _TFA_.

Comment: In the first video only half of the wipes are real.

Comment: Yeah, that was really annoying not having any indication for what the real vs fake screen wipes were..

Comment: Oh yeah... There are screen wipes all over the place in TFA.

Comment: The funny thing is, I was going to ask the same question last month.   I google searched, and found that story, so I decided it was pointless to ask.   That's why I was attuned when I watch the film in the theatre.   See my [answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/117015/3823).

Comment: Yes, he did. http://i.stack.imgur.com/0jbXR.gif

Comment: Nice @Richard!   Can I merge that into my answer, or you want to offer your own?

Comment: Merge away. I'll probably come up with a more fulsome answer when a better version of the film becomes available

Comment: @Richard:   Looking forward to it.

Comment: Of major interest: https://youtu.be/8NAhAEQUk8M

Comment: @ThePopMachine - More fulsome answer is below...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, he absolutely did. I just noted them last night. I don't know how to prove this until someone can point to a video on YouTube or a GIF, but he did.

I noted it because there is an [iris wipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wipe_(transition)) in at least one instance,  which is hard to miss because exotic wipes are very rare outside Star Wars nowadays, so it's quite conspicuous if you're looking for it.

@Richard provided this animated gif, which demonstrates a wipe between BB-8 rolling away lonesomely in Jakku and a ship in orbit.

[image]

Here's positive confirmation without the video evidence. [This article](http://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/films/news/star-wars-the-force-awakens-oscar-nominated-editors-interview-deleted-scenes-rey-diversity-jj-abrams-a6895606.html) quotes *The Force Awakens* editors Mary Jo Markey and Maryann Brandon.

> MB: It was fun using the wipes. I’m not a huge fan of that sort of thing, but the wipes were really fun to use. I think the question that was most asked before we started the film was “are you going to use the wipes?” You would think there was something they wanted to know more but that seemed to be the thing. When we asked JJ “Do you want us to do this?” he went “Of course, it's Star Wars, we have to use the wipes.” We didn’t want to overuse them but they are fun. It allows you a certain leeway for transitions.

To tie this up,  here is [a GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvzLB.gif) of a very unusual transition that has become available.

[image]

Comment: +1 for conviction!  I agree, they definitely used them.  I saw it twice, but the last time was over a month ago, and so it's hard to think of a concrete instance.  Since you saw it last night, do you happen to remember a particular scene where it was used?

Comment: I do remember the iris wipe at the very end when the end credits begin, but somehow I think I'd want more examples, since _that_ one is kind of an obligatory one, you know? lol :) +1

Comment: @Praxis I had my computer read your comment _out loud_ and it pronounced your user name as "Prasheez" lol. :)

Comment: I’m pretty sure there was an iris wipe to or from Jakku at some point, possibly after Rey meets Finn. I should probably just pop to the cinema real quick and watch it again to check, right?

Comment: @RedCaio,   Yes, I agree with Paul.   Jakku sounds right because I have a vague memory of desert terrain and I believe the other side of the wipe involved a close up of some equipment.   (This will inevitably be wrong, but I guarantee the wipe is there somewhere.)

Comment: @Praxis:   #3 for me :)

Comment: @RedCaio : lol...hmm, yours has some interesting letter combinations too, so I wonder how yours would be pronounced...  :-)

Comment: @Praxis It's Red (like the color), and Caio kind of sounds like Kyle. http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7782/54827

Comment: @RedCaio : Oh yeah, I remember your username comment. :-)  I meant, I wonder if your computer voice program would mangle it or not.  ;-)

Comment: @Praxis My computer pronounces it Red-K-O, lol :)

Comment: @RedCaio : Hehe.  :-)

Comment: From this gif, it seems the wipes are just a bit faster than in the original trilogy...

Comment: @Thomas  If you watch this:  http://youtu.be/8NAhAEQUk8M (it's excellent) you'll see that there actually is a variety of speeds of wipes in the originals depending on the pacing and purpose.

Answer (score 18):

Yes, Jar Jar Abrams used a wide variety of [standard film tricks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OAH0MoAv2CI&nohtml5=False) to cut between individual shots. At the end of each scene, he then used a screen wipe to indicate the major transition.

For ease of reference, I've also included the technical names for each wipe.

**Diagonal wipe (right)**
[image]

**Iris wipe**
[image]

**Focus Iris wipe**
[image]

**Bar Wipe (left)**
[image]

**(Reverse) Horizontal Barn Door wipe**
[image]

**Horizontal Barn Door wipe**
[image]

**Bar wipe (right)**
[image]

**Diagonal wipe (left)**
[image]

**Bar wipe (Left)**
[image]

**(Reverse) Vertical Barn Door wipe**
[image]

**Bar wipe (Left)**
[image]

**Iris wipe**
[image]

Comment: Did you do that yourself?

Comment: @ThePopMachine - No, it was a guy called JJ Abrams.

Comment: Very funny... :)

Comment: What? No red arrows or hand drawn circles? How am I supposed to figure out where in the image the wipes are? -1

Comment: I definitely looked into the third image, and it is legitimately from the movie. So if you think these images aren't authentic, then you haven't seen my Blu-Ray copy of this movie. And is THAT a world that YOU want to live and in? Didn't think so. Brunches. [peace sign]

Comment: -1 for lack of mousedrawn red arrows,  but +2 for Jar Jar Abrams!!!!

Answer (score 3):

In the first shot of the [official trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sGbxmsDFVnE), there is a shot of Rey opening an access panel, which serves as a transition from what appears to be a shot from space. As I recall, this scene *was* in the film (though I can't remember what happened right before), and I think it classifies as a wipe transition, though it's not as blatant as the ones in *Revenge of the Sith*.

Comment: Although I appreciate the attempt, that's not a wipe.  It's just a shot from inside the access panel, where the wipe-like effect is a result of the panel moving.    The rest of the trailer uses fades to/from black.   Even if there were a wipe in the trailer, it wouldn't tell us anything about wipes in the movie since trailers are edited separately from unedited footage.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Based on the second video in the original question, it looked to me like a 'wipe' could include the use of physical objects as transitions to new scenes, such as Leia's cell door closing or someone walking across the frame. And in the trailer, the shot is preceded directly by what looks to be a shot of stars, so it's a direct transition from one shot to another without fading. Like I said, I can't remember where this happens in the film, but since the star shot is pretty brief in the trailer I assume it was from a longer shot in the film.

Comment: I guess the 'stars' could just be dust, but they *really* didn't look like dust to me.