# Did Rogue One use screen wipes?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

Screen wipes are prevalent in all the other Star Wars films, but were they used in Rogue One?

Comment: No. That's why all the screens are dirty.

Comment: I vaguely remember seeing a circular wipe as the credits came in, which I think I noticed in part because I didn't remember seeing any others.

Comment: @alexwlchan - You're right. I've added it to my answer below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a single [iris wipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wipe_(transition)) at the end of the film as we move into the credits, however (see below) this isn't true for the rest of the film.

[image]

Rogue One doesn't use any of the trademark "[Star Wars Wipes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/124610/20774)" that you see in the other Star Wars films. It tends to make extensive use of audio [J-Cuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J_cut) to introduce minor scene transitions and visual [**Match-cuts**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Match_cut) to introduce major scene transitions in place of where the 'wipes' would usually go.

**The yellow light on Jyn's face matches the colour and shape of the Rogue One logo**
[image]

**The circular window in Saw Garrerra's apartment matching the shape of the planet**
[image]

**The [triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24ODL.png) formed by Tarkin's head and body matches the shape of the pyramid on Yavin**
[image]

**The blue lighting on Mon Mothma's face matches the blue of hyperspace**
[image]

**The interior lighting on Jyn's face matches the black/red of Mustafar**
[image]

---

This was a highly conscious choice by the film's director and producer to put a unique "stamp" onto the film as being ***separate and distinct from the main continuity films.***

> Producer Kathleen Kennedy was very supportive of Edwards’ desire to
> experiment and to give the film its own unique personality: **“The Star
> Wars saga films have a responsibility to maintain a continuity of tone
> and stylistic device. Things like the crawl at the beginning, and the
> wipes. But with the standalone films we’re relaxing some of those
> rules** so that we can try stylistic and tonal experiments that depart a
> bit from what we’ve seen and are exciting.”
>
> <sub><sup>[Director Gareth Edwards puts own stamp to Star Wars with “Rogue One”](https://pop.inquirer.net/2016/11/director-gareth-edwards-puts-stamp-star-wars-rogue-one/#sthash.n0AT77Rc.dpuf)</sup></sub>

Comment: "Tarkin's head matching the shape of the pyramid on Yavin" - uh ... that requires a *lot* of fantasy to recignize.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - This might help - https://i.stack.imgur.com/24ODL.png

Comment: @Valorum I'm getting a certificate warning for your imgur link.

Comment: @Valorum: Well, I guess that works for almost any two images that feature some contours ;)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper -Indeed, and if it wasn't **one example out of half a dozen**, you could certainly argue that it was a coincidence.

Comment: @jcm - Weird. It's working fine for me. Possibly a browser issue?

Answer (score 0):

Screen wipe happened once when introducing death star, it wasn't a wipe necessarily, but the immense shadow over a star destroyer

Comment: I think the point was that it **wasn't a wipe**. The director used shadow to make it look like a wipe was happening, then subverted it.